# How to display single instance of SAS in multiple windows on Windows 7

Tags: sas, windows-7-x64

I saw  [a demonstration in SAS on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKpSqSdnQIE) in which the explorer, output, log, and program editor all appeared in what looked to be independent windows.  The video looked to be on a Mac, but is there a way to separate windows like that on a Microsoft machine?  I have SAS 9.4.

(I've looked around online and played around in the menu, but maybe I'm using the wrong search terms?)

Comment: It depends, if you're using SAS Studio there appear to be ways because it's browser based. But not within SAS Base or EG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display Manager under Windows encapsulates all of the various SAS windows (PGM, Log, Output, etc) inside of one window.  On Unix (which is what the video is showing) SAS just uses the normal X-Windows window manager to manage the individual windows.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation.